graphql - must have exactly one non-nullable unique identifier. Accepted names: id, or ID
Schema:
type Delivery {
  """
  Delivery Status
  """
  deliveryStatus: String
  """
  Provider
  """
  provider: Provider
}

type Provider {
  """
  Provider Type
  """
  type: String
  """
  Provider Name
  """
  name: String!
}

I receive the following error from eslint:
error  type "Provider" must have exactly one non-nullable unique identifier.
Accepted names: id, or ID.

This graphql endpoint is publishing an existing API, but with extra information appended to it where it was more efficient to do so in the endpoint than via a supergraph.
As such, there are no ID's for the providers.
Anyone any ideas what I can do here please?

You need to add id field in the Provider type like below.
type Provider {
  """
  Provider unique id
  """
  id: ID! // ADD THIS

  """
  Provider Type
  """
  type: String
  """
  Provider Name
  """
  name: String!
}


Hi Alish. Even if the id doesn't exist in the response?

Yes to fix the issue you have to add id field on the Provider object. However, if id field is not present then consult with you backend they shold send some form of id for Provider.
